# Determining proxy server/port

Tags: proxy, pac

I apologize if this is a simplistic question, I am not familiar with this kind of thing.

I am trying to determine my proxy server ip and port number in order to use a google calendar syncing program. I downloaded the proxy.pac file using google chrome. The last line reads:

```
return "PROXY proxyhost:1081";
```

I believe that means the port number is 1081, but for the proxy server, I was expecting something with the format "proxy.example.com" Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you expecting a hostname containing dots? Why not just use `proxyhost` as specified by your script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using the Windows operating system?

You can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, input "cmd" in the run box, you will get the "command Prompt", then input the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

command 1

```
ipconfig  /all | find /i "Dns Suffix"
```

it will show something like this.

> Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : xxx.xxx.xxx

command 2

```
ping proxyhost
```

it will show something like this.

> Pinging proxyhost.xxx.xxx.xxx [yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy] with 32 bytes of data:
>   Reply from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=60

Then maybe "proxyhost.xxx.xxx.xxx" is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following into windows commandline

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

It will return

```
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Proxy Servers(s) : your.proxy.address.com:port
```

Comment: For me it's showing as below.
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:
    Direct access (no proxy server).
Does it mean no proxy enabled right? but, still jars are not getting downloaded from maven repository.

Comment: @Pand005 I'm behind a proxy and it shows that message also. I think this method is unfortunately not always reliable. Ah more info here: https://superuser.com/a/815486/268750