# Googleapis.com Unknown Host Exception

Tags: java, google-books

Following Problem: I'm trying to get Information over the Google Books API, i found [this Example](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/books-cmdline-sample), but if i excute this it get the following Error.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.googleapis.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
at de.example.books.Main.queryGoogleBooks(Main.java:44)
at de.example.books.Main.main(Main.java:145)
```

In Main Line 44: Volumes volumes = volumesList.execute();

I hope you understand my question, my english isn't perfect. :/

Comment: Try pinging "ping www.googleapis.com" - maybe your firewall is preventing you

Comment: That is it! In CMD it dosent work! How i configure this in the firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comment about testing you can reach the server using ping -

ping www.googleapis.com

You need to check with your admin that you are allowed to bypass, and maybe ask them to add a rule to serve googleapi's.

It also might be that you need to setup a proxy to allow java to call googleapi's - can you access the url from a browser

Comment: I had to settup a proxy with that following tow lines, because my Computer is in a university network with a proxy.

  System.setProperty("proxyPort", "1234");
  System.setProperty("proxyHost", "123.123.123.123");

Comment: How do i got proxyPort and proxyHost. Whether it is the host for my server or fcm google api server.??Please help me out i got stuck in here

Comment: Soemthing like this with ipconfig http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338908/determining-proxy-server-port